# Not getting proper status from CrossGeofences.Current.RegionStatusChanged in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using CrossGeofences Plugin For Xamarin forms 
Here is the example:
https://github.com/aritchie/geofences/blob/master/README.md

But The Enter/Exit status is not proper
here is my code
For starting Geofence:

```
GeofenceRegion region = new GeofenceRegion("Vejdhaba", new Plugin.Geofencing.Position(Convert.ToDouble(Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(Longitude)),
                                Distance.FromMeters(150));
                        CrossGeofences.Current.StartMonitoring(region);
```

And Inside the App.xaml.cs

```
CrossGeofences.Current.RegionStatusChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var region = args.Region;
                var status = args.Status;

                if (args.Status == GeofenceStatus.Entered)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IFClass>().SendNotification("Status", "Entered to geofence");
                }
                if (args.Status == GeofenceStatus.Exited)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IFClass>().SendNotification("Status", "geofence Exited");
                }
                if (args.Status == GeofenceStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IFClass>().SendNotification("Status", "geofence Unknown");
                }
            };
```

the status is not getting properly
**how to solve this?**

Comment: Please elaborate your issue i am not able to understand what exactly isn't working here

Comment: My aplication needs geofencing ,and here I am using geofencing plugin.But when the user enter the area of the center point then it will not notify the user.

Comment: Whether the appropriate permissions, including runtime permissions, are requested